# Proof of $\frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a + x^{n-3}a^3+...+xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the proof behind the formula $\frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a + x^{n-3}a^3+...+xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$

Please help. I don't even know how to begin.

Comment: Do you know  how to divide one polynomial by another?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can't you just multiply and simplify as I have done?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I know only by long division method. Is there any other method?

Comment: I am assuming that OP wants to know  how to discover the identity. @ParclyTaxel

Comment: Are you sure of $x^{n-3}a^3$? Isn't it $x^{n-3}a^2$?